# How to check if two different or same elements are next to each other in a vector or array?

Tags: c++, c, numbers

I am wondering how to check if two numbers or elements are next by each other in a vector.

Here is what I have coded so far and tried:

```
// Check stack postfix, to see if operator needs to be pushed on
         for (int it = 0; it < postfixstack.size(); it++)
         {
             int count = 0; // keeps track of how many numbers

                              // If number, continue, else....do something?
             if (isdigit(it))
             {
                 count++;
                 continue;
             }

             else
                              // do something if element is not a number

         }
```

I am having some luck using the sstream header

Comment: You mean like `std::adjacent_find`?

Comment: what does adjacent_find do? I am kinda new to vector functions. I just know the basics, like push_back and cbegin

Comment: Assuming postfixstack.size() > 0, and you have a sanity check for it + 1 `if( postfixstack[ it ] == postfixstack[ it + 1 ] )`

Comment: that's correct, I just looked up Adjacent_find on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/adjacent_find/

and @TheFloatingBrain Yes correct the vector will have elements in it already. Although does not have to be the same numbers it can be different numbers.

Comment: @user110182 sorry I thought you wanted to check for example `vec[0] = 2; vec[1] = 2; //<--- are these the same.//`

Comment: its okay. I am just wondering if there is any way to do it? I am not sure there is.

Comment: Sort your vector first.  Then look at the previous and present slots.